# VS 2008: Link command includes library I didn't ask for and doesn't exist

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, linker

I am trying to reorganize a C++ project that was developed in C++ so that it is possible to have different versions of the product for different customers.  After wrestling with it for a day or more, I've got most of it done.  The last project, which builds the executable file, is refusing to link because a library does not exist.  I did not specify that library in the list of libraries that are to be linked against.  I am not specifying any folders with the libraries I am asking for.  Instead, I list an additional library folder that appears in a LIBPATH option, as expected.  At the end of the linker command line, the libraries I need are included with no folder names, and then they are repeated, this time with folder names.  And there is also one library that does not exist in there.  I can't see where those extra files are coming from.  The missing library is "generaledit.lib", and here is the linker command line:

```
/OUT:"..\Debug Stripco\Caps.exe" /INCREMENTAL:NO /NOLOGO 
/LIBPATH:"..\Debug Stripco/Lib" 
/LIBPATH:"..\Debug Stripco/../Lib" 
/MANIFEST 
/MANIFESTFILE:"Debug Stripco\Caps.exe.intermediate.manifest"             
/MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" 
/NODEFAULTLIB:"libc.lib" /NODEFAULTLIB:"libcmt.lib" 
/NODEFAULTLIB:"msvcrt.lib" /NODEFAULTLIB:"libcd.lib"    
/NODEFAULTLIB:"libcmtd.lib" /NODEFAULTLIB:"nafxcwd.lib"     
/NODEFAULTLIB:"uafxcwd.lib" 
/DEBUG 
/PDB:"c:\CAPS Builds\trunk\Debug Stripco\/Caps.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS     
/ENTRY:"wWinMainCRTStartup" /DYNAMICBASE:NO /MACHINE:X86 /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT 
CapsLib.lib CapsData.lib ManCharge.lib CJ60Lib.lib BaseEdit.lib FceEdit.lib 
CycleEdit.lib InnerCoverEdit.lib CoolingCoverEdit.lib SeperatorPlateEdit.lib 
InventoryEdit.lib Htmlhelp.lib ConfigureDlgs.lib CommonDlgs.lib     
CrashRpt1401.lib CrashRptProbe1401.lib 
"..\debug stripco\lib\capshelper.lib" 
"..\debug stripco\lib\generaledit.lib" 
"..\debug stripco\lib\inistl.lib"
```

Where are those "..\debug stripco\lib..." lines coming from, and how can I get rid of generaledit.lib, which I never asked for?

Thank you very much.

Comment: May be add line breaks to make your linker command line readable.

Comment: Thank you.  Done.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.  The generaledit project was in the list of projects on which my main project depended.